# Email attachment missing using Java Mail API

Tags: java, email

I'm using the latest version of the Java Mail API (1.5.6) and I'm trying to send an email with an attachment. If the attachment is plain/txt, then it works, but if it's PDF or XML, then the attachment is not included in the email with ***some*** email clients. I've been debugging this using a Gmail account with the Thunderbird email client on Ubuntu.

If I send an email with a simple one-line plain-text message body and a very simple XML attachment file, I can see the attachment when viewing my Gmail account through a browser. But when I use Thunderbird setup for the same Gmail account, I only see the message body; there is no attachment.

There's no reference to an attachment being blocked or anything like that. Now, if I send the exact same email manually from some email account, including the exact same attachment file, I ***can*** see the attachment in Thunderbird. Also, if I send the email (same message body, same attachment file) using the `ssmtp` application from the command line like this:

```
echo -e "To: recipient@gmail.com\nFrom: my.account@gmail.ie\nSubject: SSMTP Attachment Test\n\nSome message body here...\n"| (cat - && uuencode /tmp/attach.xml attach.xml) | ssmtp recipient@gmail.com
```

... I also ***can*** see the attachment.

So, the conclusion I've come to is that the Java Mail API is composing messages incorrectly, which is causing ***some*** email clients to ignore attachments. Here's my Java code for sending the attachment:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    String sender = "my.account@gmail.com";

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
       new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(sender, "my.pass.word");
        }
    });
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);

    mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
    mimeMessage.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("recipient@gmail.com"));
    mimeMessage.setSubject("Java Attachment Test");
    MimeMultipart mimeMultiPart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

    BodyPart plainTextBody = new MimeBodyPart();
    plainTextBody.setContent("Some message body here...", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN.getMimeType());
    mimeMultiPart.addBodyPart(plainTextBody);    

    MimeBodyPart attachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    attachmentBodyPart.attachFile( new File("/tmp/attach.xml") );
    mimeMultiPart.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart);

    mimeMessage.setContent(mimeMultiPart);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    mimeMessage.writeTo(outputStream);

    Transport.send(mimeMessage);
}
```

I've examined the raw email message that gets sent by the above code.
The relevant parts concerning the email content itself at the end of the raw message are:

> Date: Mon, 17 Oct 2016 05:47:13 -0700 (PDT)
>   From: my.account@gmail.com
>   To: recipient@gmail.com
>   Message-ID: <1919892312.2.1476708432597@my-laptop>
>   Subject: Java Attachment Test
>   MIME-Version: 1.0
>   Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>   boundary="----=_Part_0_824318946.1476708432531"
>
> ------=_Part_0_824318946.1476708432531
>   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>
> Some message body here...
>   ------=_Part_0_824318946.1476708432531
>   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=us-ascii; name=attach.xml
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=attach.xml
>
> <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><SomeTag>This is an XML
>   attachment for the attachment test !!</SomeTag>
>
> ------=_Part_0_824318946.1476708432531--

I know for a fact that this issue is not isolated to Thunderbird, at least one other free public email client that I know of has this issue.

Just for comparison, here's the relevant part of the raw message from Thunderbird sent using SSMTP (which does include the attachment):

> Date: Mon, 17 Oct 2016 12:41:00 +0000
>   To: recipient@gmail.com
>   From: my.account@gmail.com
>   Subject: SSMTP Attachment Test
>   Message-ID: <01020157d2a8ce09-de09d6dc-9845-405b-be1c-de31fe3ab5e1-000000@eu-west-1.amazonses.com>
>   X-SES-Outgoing: 2016.10.17-54.240.4.10
>   Feedback-ID: 1.eu-west-1.N9gzKAXN1Z0obJtDShqnt2QFE+TWuvGkNu10M6VFpIM=:AmazonSES
>
> Some message body here...
>
> begin 664 attach.xml
>   M/#]X;6P@=F5R<VEO;CU<(C$N,%PB(&5N8V]D:6YG/5PB551&+3A<(C\^/%-O
>   M;65486<^5&AI<R!I<R!A;B!834P@871T86-H;65N="!F;W(@=&AE(&%T=&%C
>   8:&UE;G0@=&5S="`A(3PO4V]M951A9SX*
>   `
>   end

Comment: You may want to eliminate some possible points of failure by simplifying your file attachment code, by using the [attachFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method instead of setting the details of the attachment yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that method was there. It still produces the same result though. No attachment, and the raw message looks identical.